# header on first page and others

Tags: r, r-markdown

a header is created for pages 2+ with fancyhdr but how can you make the same header also appear on the first page?

here is the rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
classoption: landscape
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: false
    dev: pdf
    keep_tex: false
    toc: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[C]{center text}
- \fancyhead[R]{right text}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include `\thispagestyle{fancy}` in the beginning of your document (e.g. just after the yaml header) to make the first page fancy.

[image]

**Edit to address your comment**

If you want to have different center text in the first page you can have use if when you define `\fancyhead`

```
\fancyhead[C]{\ifnum\value{page}>1 center text \else \fi}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Given that the title page already has a title on it, is there a way, for just the title page, to make the left text be null instead of "Contents"?

Comment: Cool. Thank you.